# get the list of nodes and node-text that contains specific text using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, plsql, oracle-apex

I am playing around with parsing XML files on remote server using oracle apex and pl/sql. I use `APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST` to get the xml file into a clob variable and then use XPATH and XMLTable to get specific text.

Here's a sample XML file that I have (note that, the original file is quite complex, this is only the representation of the content in the file):

```
<article>
  <index>
    <term>term1</term>
    <term>term2</term>
  </index>
  <ul>
    <li>this is text with term1</li>
  </ul>
  <p>this is another text with term1</p>
  <p>this is text with term2</p>
</article>
<article>
  <index>
    <term>term2</term>
    <term>term3</term>
  </index>
  <ul>
    <li>this is text with term2</li>
  </ul>
  <p>this is another text with term1</p>
  <p>this is text with term2</p>
</article>
```

Here's what I am trying to do with this file:

1. Get a list of nodes that contain 'term1' in the text.
2. Get the line of text that contain 'term1'

In this example, I should get the following:

```
li: this is text with term1
p: this is another text with term1
```

and so on.

I am able to do a general text search, but it returns everything under the article, and not only the element that is required. For this example, I would get `ul` as well as `li` in the results, where as I only want `li` and the text within it.

```
FOR r IN (  SELECT rownum rn, termtext 
               FROM xmltable('/article//*[contains(.,"term1")]' passing XMLTYPE(sourceXML)
                                         columns termtext VARCHAR2(500) PATH '.')
            )
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row: '||r.rn);      
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Text: '||r.termtext);      

   END LOOP;
```

`sourceXML` is the clob that contains xml file.

Can someone suggest the correct xpath to be used for such?

Comment: did you try setting a filter to get your target node? Maybe `/article//*[self::p or self::li][contains(.,"term1")]`

Comment: @joel I thought of that, but `p` and `li` are just the example tags. It could be any number of such elements that can have the term. Hence I can't set specific tag filters. What I want right now is the immediate element and text within it that contains the term. Where as currently, I get everything, parent elements, child elements and all the text in them. As in, for example I gave, I get`ul` and `li` both in the results.

Comment: In that case, you should use the `text()` node. Use `contains(text(),"term1")` instead.

Comment: hey that worked :). Thanks. One question though. I could get the text inside the node, I also want to store the name of the node and check which node does the text belongs to, whether it is `p` or `li` or `span` and so on. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: use `/article//*[self::p or self::li][contains(text(),'term1')]/name()`

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen One issue. I could use xpath with `'contains(text(),"term1")]` successfully in VSCODe editor, but when I added it to the code, it throws error `[XPTY0004] Expression type does not match a required type`. This is what I have in code: ```SELECT rownum rn, termtext 
               FROM xmltable('/article//*[contains(text(),"term1")]' passing XMLTYPE(sourceXML)
                                         columns termtext VARCHAR2(500) PATH '.')```